# What is the largest size a Facebook group can become?

Tags: facebook, facebook-groups

What is the largest number of people who can be members of a Facebook group?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on the setup.
Whether old Facebook group or new Facebook group.
With old it is pretty unlimited (there maybe some saturation that can be reached)

With the new since the default groups are closed then it is limited by the creator/moderator of the group. I know for at least one of the new groups I have joined, chat is broken after ~250 members.